# Finding the maximum amplitide quantitatively using interpolation

Tags: interpolation

I have the following table

```
data = Table[Sin[i], {i, 0, 10, 0.1}] // N
```

And I plotted the data as follows,

Now I want to know the value of each maximum with high accuracy. It can see that for example the first maximum is around 1.0. However, I want it in terms of an accurate number. Can I do it using interpolation? If yes, how can I know what should be the accurate starting point?

I appreciate it if you could help me.

[image]

Comment: From data with machine precision you can not get an exact answer. Exact means infinite precision. For this you need an analytic procedure, like setting the derivative to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Find the peaks

```
peaks = FindPeaks[data]
```

{{17, 0.999574}, {80, 0.998941}}

But the "accurate number" should be `1`

```
FunctionRange[Sin[x], x, y]
```

-1 <= y <= 1

Hence

```
Round[peaks, 1]
```

{{17, 1}, {80, 1}}

To find the corresponding x-values:

```
x /. Solve[Sin[x] == 1, x] /. C[1] :> {0, 1} // Flatten
```

{Pi/2, (5*Pi)/2}

```
ListLinePlot[data, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point @ FindPeaks[data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're most welcome

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a graphical solution. The procedure can be used universally, not just specifically for the data given here. To get a more accurate solution I increased the resolution by 10.

```
data = Table[Sin[i], {i, 0, 10, 0.01}];
f = Interpolation@data;
p = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1000}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {f'[#] &}, MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize@Medium}] //Quiet
```

[image]

```
 pts = Cases[p, Point[{x_, y_ /; y > 0}] :> {x/100, y}, \[Infinity]] //Sort
```

{{1.5808, 0.999999}, {7.86396, 0.999999}}